# Can I make Ethers Wallet Addresses pass RSK Testnet case checksum test?

Tags: ethers.js, rsk

On RSK public testnet, I create my RSK wallet with ethers like this:

```
const wallet = await ethers.Wallet.createRandom()
```

Then the address is: `0x68C06960f0Cd2bB0318673F157243Ad545AbbE2A`

When I send an amount to it, and explore the transaction on RSK testnet explorer, the actual destination address of the transaction has a difference in case (EIP-1191) `0x68C06960f0CD2bB0318673f157243aD545AbBE2a`

How can I make ethers generate the address in the right checksum case right away? Does it really matter at the end?
Ideally, I would like to be enforce the chainId in the transaction request so that I am sure that my transaction will not occur on any other chain than RSK.

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the the function responsible for formatting addresses, [`ethers.utils.getAddress(address)`](https://github.com/ethers-io/ethers.js/blob/master/packages/address/src.ts/index.ts#L77-L113), does not take `chainId` as a param, and therefore it won't be able to produce EIP-1191 checksums.

In this case you might need to either (1) roll your own EIP-1191 implementation and invoke that after getting addresses from ethers.js, or (2) convert addresses to all lower-case or all upper-case as a workaround (which bypasses any checksum verification)

Comment: Ok, I ll go for all lowercase and not set the chainId in the transaction request

Answer (score 2):

As the comment above mentions, ethers doesn't accept the chainId as a property, however, the [@rsksmart/rsk-util](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@rsksmart/rsk-utils) library does. Specifically, the [toChecksumAddress()](https://github.com/rsksmart/rsk-utils/blob/master/src/addresses.js#L30-L38) method.

It would be like this:

```js
import { toChecksumAddress } from 'rskjs-util'

const address = "0x3Dd03d7d6c3137f1Eb7582Ba5957b8A2e26f304A"
const chainId = 30 // RSK Mainnet, 31 is RSK Testnet

const checksum = toChecksumAddress(address, chainId)

console.log(checksum) // 0x3DD03d7d6c3137f1EB7582bA5957b8A2e26F304A
```

If you pass a RSK checksummed address to Ethers it will throw an error that the checksum is incorrect. This is because Ethers only checks for the Ethereum version. So, before sending an address back to Ethers, convert it to lowercase.

The checksum should be used when you are displaying it to the end user. It won't prevent an address being used on multiple networks, but it is an indication/caution to the user that perhaps the address they typed/pasted in might be for a different network.

About a year ago I wrote a blog post about this, [Checksums are for humans, not computers](https://developerjesse.com/2021/04/13/checksums.html).

Comment: Thanks for the useful info Jesse Clark, and the blog post was clear as well. I was still surprised though by its title, it seems counter intuitive. So basically I will never able to send a transaction with Ethers if the chainId specified does not use EIP-55.

Comment: Correct, since Ethers was originally written by Ethereum devs and for Ethereum, it will only accept the mainnet checksum or lowercase. Perhaps in a future releases they will add it.